# SQL Server Transaction Log Full affect on FileStream

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transaction-log, blob, filestream

These are general question I would like to receive some inputs from experts with BLOB SQL Data.

1. How will SQL Server Transaction Log (.ldf file) linked to SQL Server FileStream
2. Is it different from general structured data processing i.e., Log Records , VLFs and write ahead Logging . I mean when the Database is with FileStream will there be any additional T Log processing ? Would like to understand more !
3. What is the difference between T Log and $FSLOG ?
4. If SQL Server T Log is full and out of drive space , it affects all Database Engine related transactions including FILESTREAM correct ?
5. Please explain the flow of a FILESTREAM related Database engine transaction.

Best Regards